# iOS 6 MapKit VoiceOver Reads POIs Prior to Pins

Tags: ios, mapkit, accessibility, voiceover, ios6-maps

I have code that worked fine under iOS 5 while tested under VoiceOver. My code adds a collection of `MKPinAnnotationViews` to a `MKMapView`. My problem in iOS 6 is that voiceover reads street names and other POIs (which can be many) prior to reaching the pins I have added. Is there a way to reorder these? I can't seem to find any recommendation from Apple on how to add pins to maps for iOS 6.

Thanks!

Comment: Great question. I'm having the same issues myself.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle your situation is **using the rotor** to order and select only the annotations you specify in your predicate.

To understand how that should be implemented, I suggest you take a look at the **WWDC 2016 - What's New in Accessibility** video whose content is perfectly summarized [here](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-16202.html) and that fully explains how this feature works thanks to a detailed example.